# Wrong width using em in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I use "em" to set the width of some divs. Above those divs is another div which has the same width as all the other ones below together. See graphic below:

```
|          9.6em        |
|2.4em|2.4em|2.4em|2.4em|
```

Simple jSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QxvrR/

This works on Firefox and Chrome but on Safari (7.0) the top div is slightly longer than the ones below. In the end the browsers convert em to px and it seems that Safari can not handle widths with non integer sizes (the lower boxes are 38.4px).

The example above is extremely simplified to show the problem. Does somebody have a solution/workaround for this besides falling back to px dimensions?

Comment: Use Javascript to round 2.4em to whole pixels and then calculate the top width as 4x those pixels. There is currently no way to do it in CSS.

Comment: @MrLister In the mean time I made a test with IE too and it works. It seems to be specific to Safari so I guess there is really no other way than to use pixels.